# jQuery, display result of function on next click

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento2

I trying to make auto price calculation on magento 2.1 product. When i test my code on snippet or jsfiddle it works normally, but when runs on real magento site the result of "mouseup" calculate function will display on next click (or from previous click) but on "keyup" worked fine. Did someone have any answers for this case?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".control").on("keyup mouseup",function(){
        var totale = 0;
        $(".quantity-number .qty").each(function () {
            var qty = parseFloat($(this).val());
            //var price = parseFloat($(".price-wrapper").attr("data-price-amount"));
            //var price = parseFloat($(".price").attr("data-price-amount"));
            //var price = parseFloat($(".price").text());
            
            var price = parseFloat($('.product-info-main span.price').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
            
            /*
            var temp=$(".price").text();
            var num = temp.match(/[\d\.]+/g);
            if (num != null){
                var price = num.toString();
            }
            */
            totale +=  qty * price;
            totale =  qty * price;
        });
        $(".cal-price").html("฿"+totale.toFixed(2));
    }); 
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <div class="product-info-main">
    <span class="price-wrapper" data-price-amount="10">
    <span class="price">
    ฿10.00
    </span>
    <div class="control">
        <div class="quantity-number">
            <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Quantity" class="input-text qty">
    </div>
    <span class="cal-price"></span>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/l2esforu/x6332ay3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is SOLVED! thanks

After try using every state may happening on main div.

```
$(document).on("input keyup change click mouseup",".control",function(){
   $(".quantity-number .qty").each(function () {
      //do stuff
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to call the function when the value is changed in the input element, add an event listener for the "input" event on the input element itself.

`$("#qty").on("input", function () { ... });`

However, if you have several quantity inputs, and they are added dynamically, you will want to use a delegate selector like so:

```
$(".control").on("input", ".qty", function () {
  // do stuff
});
```

[Event Delegation Docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Now, i updated the code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/l2esforu/x6332ay3/3/
It's work fine as the old, but on Magento site not show any results.
please see: http://prntscr.com/ec1acp